# Check constraint in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, check-constraints

Is it possible in MongoDb to add a check constraint that a value should be in a range? Like in SQL you would say

ALTER TABLE GpsData ADD CONSTRAINT CK_X_not_0 CHECK (X <> 0)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a [Schema Validation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/) feature in Mongodb since 3.2

Although I believe it's not as versatile as SQL constraints in most popular engines, it should be more than enough for most use cases.